# Codewars Python TDD offline

Tags: python, tdd

I want to do Codewars Python katas offline using my familiar development environment. However the tests provided use a completely different syntax to Python's Unittest. I can't find the source code for the test framework anywhere.

I've tried the codewars-client npm package (https://github.com/shime/codewars) but it confuses me deeply. I've also looked at the codewars-cli runner but that looks even more difficult to grok, and involves Docker.

It's frustrating because I really just want to practice some basic coding but I'm ending up having to try to understand json and dependencies and package management just to get a basic TDD environment up and running.

Can anyone please advise on how to simply make it possible to use the tests provided in the python katas locally? Example below:

```
test.describe("Basic tests")
test.it("A resistor under 1000 ohms and with only three bands")   
test.assert_equals(decode_resistor_colors("yellow violet black"), "47 ohms, 20%")
test.it("A resistor between 1000 and 999999 ohms, with a gold fourth band")   
test.assert_equals(decode_resistor_colors("yellow violet red gold"), "4.7k ohms, 5%")
test.it("A resistor of 1000000 ohms or above, with a silver fourth band")   
test.assert_equals(decode_resistor_colors("brown black green silver"), "1M ohms, 10%")
```

Comment: You could implement those functions yourself, put them in a file named test.py and import it. There's also seri/gettc for topcoder which I'm having a better time with than shime/codewars. Occasionally I have had to fix small bugs in the test code or verify manually because of multiple acceptable answers while using gettc

Answer (score 1):

I just convert the test cases to print statements in my code and comment out the rest. Then visually compare the answers.

See below:

```
# test.describe("Basic tests")
# test.it("A resistor under 1000 ohms and with only three bands")   
print(decode_resistor_colors("yellow violet black")) # "47 ohms, 20%"

# test.it("A resistor between 1000 and 999999 ohms, with a gold fourth band")   
print(decode_resistor_colors("yellow violet red gold")) #  "4.7k ohms, 5%"

# test.it("A resistor of 1000000 ohms or above, with a silver fourth band")   
print(decode_resistor_colors("brown black green silver")) # "1M ohms, 10%"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using something like [python-code-kata](https://github.com/vegaspy/python-code-kata)
You can use a current example or search for some other code kata.
The principal is the same as at "codewars" - it uses tests to check your answer. The main benefit is that you can set it up on your machine and use it offline. (Which as I understand is important for you)